# Return recursive method

Tags: java, methods

Why in this recursive method:

```java
public static int contaCaratteri1(String qq, char bb, int ripp, int poss) {
    if (poss > qq.length() - 1) {
        return ripp;
    } else {
        if (bb == qq.charAt(poss)) {
            return contaCaratteri1(qq, bb, ripp + 1, poss + 1);
        } else {
            return contaCaratteri1(qq, bb, ripp, poss + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I can return even though `return contaCaratteri1(qq,bb,ripp+1,poss+1);` are not int but, in this one:

```
public static void palindroma(String k, int i, int j) {
    if (i > j && j < i) {
        System.out.print("La stringa e' palindroma");
        return;
    } else {
        if (k.charAt(i) == k.charAt(j)) {
            return palindroma(k, i + 1, j - 1);
        } else {
            System.out.print("La stringa NON e' palindroma");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't because it is not void

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please check this page https://stackoverflow.com/tour. It will help you to create better, more detailed and focused questions.

Comment: re: *return contaCaratteri1(qq,bb,ripp+1,poss+1);" are not int*  -- yes, it is.  contaCaratteri1 returns an int value and can therefore be used where an int value is needed.

Comment: By the way:  this  `if (i > j && j < i)` says the same thing twice.  `i < j` and `j > i` are equivalent comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

The `palindroma` function should return `boolean` by design to be called recursively thus it cannot have `void` return type.

Also, `else` part of `if` statements may be removed when `return` statements are used to simplify the code:

```java
public static boolean palindroma(String k, int i, int j) {
    if (null == k) {  // check for null
        return false;
    }
    if (i > j && j < i) {
        System.out.print("La stringa e' palindroma");
        return true;
    }
    if (k.charAt(i) == k.charAt(j)) {
        return palindroma(k, i + 1, j - 1);
    }
    System.out.print("La stringa NON e' palindroma");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Normally when we create a function we try to get a value in return with ( return 0) to see if the function is terminating correctly.
some functions are predefined in the compiler
or programming language .( ex: return, void, int , char)

suppose we write a simple program in 'C' programming language with declaration. such as

void main() {

}
// here no value cannot be expected as return. because you have declared the function as NULL.

//as we know,  this does not mean that the program will not run or terminate correctly, but we cannot write a return value at the end of the function ( because function already declared as NULL/ VOID)

suppose we write a program
with no value expected in return at the end of completion of a function.
it normally returns as void

So Void is predefined as NULL inside compiler and also void function does not take any arguments .

kindly refer to wikipedia article:-

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_type

Comment: This isn't C, this isn't the main function in C, and you're not even answering the quesiton.

Comment: Not to mention that a void method in Java can take arguments.